# Shortcut to switch between (Fixed and Normal) Marque tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-photoshop-elements

[image]

Hi everyone, I love the fixed size marque tool so I can get the marque tool pixels I need. An annoyance occurs when I am deep in photoshop and have to manually scroll all the way up and click normal marque too. After a while this causes extra time, is there a tip to quickly switch between Fixed and Normal Style Marque tools?

Comment: You can set up **Tool Presets**, then have that *panel* visible to click.